# JENKINS - A pipeline doesn`t run

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, master-slave

I have some issues to run a Jenkins pipeline job. It doesn`t run in a slave node when the master node is offline. I have 1 executor in slave node and 1 executor in master, but I want to force offline the master node.
When I try to run the pipeline, it is waiting the master node to be online.
Run the pipeline project only when the master node is Online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, the pipeline script runs on the master node.